# Getting rid of gray background in CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

[In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL0ZC.png), how do I get rid of the gray background that automatically appears when I create my CSS header?

```css
.header {
        padding: 60px;
        margin: 20px auto auto auto;
        width: 1400px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #1abc9c;
        color: white;
      }
      
      body {
        background: #f2f2f2;
      }

      .search {
        width: 100%;

        position: relative;
        display: flex;
      }

      .searchTerm {
        width: 4500px;
        border: 3px solid #1abc9c;
        border-right: none;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        outline: none;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .searchTerm:focus {
        color: black;
      }

      .searchButton {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #1abc9c;
        background: #1abc9c;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      /*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
      .wrap {
        width: 30%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 900px;
        margin: auto;
      }
```

```html
<div class="header">
      <h1 style="font-size: 100px;">HI</h1>
      <p style="font-size: 30px;">
        Hello
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" class="searchTerm" id="input_text" />
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton" onclick="send_text()">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search"></div>
```

Thanks!

When I add this CSS and HTML I start getting that gray background around the header. However when I comment out the code for the search bar the header does not have the gray background.

Comment: Please add the HTML too

Comment: probably something wrong with your `html`, `css` is working fine here!

Comment: Have you tried setting `body`'s property `background: white;`? The `.header` CSS has no issue.

Comment: @ElysianStorm Yes, the body's property is currently white.

Comment: There is no issue with the `.header` can you show your other CSS attributes as well.

Comment: @ElysianStorm I just uploaded the CSS and HTML for the search bar. The header area starts getting the gray background once I add the code for the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are using this in your `css`, it is creating `greyish` background in your html:

```
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Сheck that the html has a class .header
2. Try changing the background-color of the .header and see what happens
3. Try setting the background-color for the body and see what happens

Comment: I've tried all of them and it still has the gray shade.